# Split USB from iPod to both aftermarket and factory car head unit

Tags: ipod, car-integration

I have an iPod Classic. I also have a 2017 Mazda 3 in which I installed a new stereo system with an aftermarket Pioneer head unit. The iPod works great with the Pioneer, no problems there. However, I went to great lengths to leave the factory receiver and display screen intact to be able to at least utilize the backup camera.

I'm curious to know if it is possible to split the USB cable coming from the iPod and have it interact with the aftermarket head unit for iPod control and audio, while also sending the split signal to the factory head to utilize its display capabilities?